# How to upload a binary file like an image to an aws api gateway using serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using Serverless Framework to spin up a lambda function which is invoked by an API gateway.
I want to upload an image to the api and write it to an s3 bucket. But there seems to be a problem with the encoding when I receive the image on the function.

I've already tried and failed with (serverless-apigw-binary).\

*Current Code*

```
const author = getUserName(this.head.ssid);
writeFile(author + "/" + this.head.title + "/index.jpg", this.img)
       .then(_ => {
            resolve(forMessage("Success"));
        }).catch(err => resolve(forError(err.toString())))
```

*writeFile function*

```
import {S3} from "aws-sdk"

const s3 = new S3({accessKeyId: process.env["KEY"], secretAccessKey: process.env["SECRET"]});

export function writeFile(Key: string, Body: string | Buffer) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.putObject({Key, Bucket: process.env["BUCKET_ARTICLE"], Body}, (err, data) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(data);
        })
    })
}
```

*serverless config*

```
plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - 'image/jpeg'

functions:
  upload:
    handler: src/functions/upload.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: upload
          method: post
          contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY
          cors:
            origins:
              - 'http://localhost:5000'
            headers:
              - MY_CUSTOM_HEADER
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
```

I am using postman to upload the image.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: @noetix When I write receive the image, it's encoding is different from the one the client sent. I tried doing Buffer.from(img, "binary") and Buffer.from(img,"base64"). But it doesn't work. The image is not valid any more.

Comment: Hi @AniketPrajapati, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @DrorWeiss nope